# SQL Server trigger delete existing row and INSERTED itself

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to delete an existing row when a new row is inserted.

For example, there is an existing row where its status is `ready` and ID is `2478`.

When a new row is inserted, let's say status is `completed` and ID is `2478`, the trigger would find matching ID `2478` and delete the row since status is `completed`.

At the same time, I also need to delete the inserted row as well (one with status `completed`)

Can this be done with trigger? ex: `AFTER INSERT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in a trigger. The example below deletes all rows for a given ID whenever a row with status `completed` is inserted for that ID.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(
     ID int
    ,Status varchar(10)
        CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY(ID, Status)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable
FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE target
FROM dbo.YourTable AS target
JOIN inserted ON inserted.ID = target.ID
WHERE inserted.Status = 'completed';
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable VALUES(2478,'pending');
SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable; 
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable VALUES(2478,'ready');
SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable; 
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable VALUES(2478,'completed');
SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable; 
GO
```

Comment: based on your answer, the table will be empty right?

Comment: Yes, the table will end up empty in with the sample data in my answer. If you insert rows for other IDs and a non-completed status, those will not be deleted.